Displaying Popup But Should be Stop When User Click on Stop
here is the detail code of my website https://lunchtimeprediction.com/ . My popup is working fine. I have just create it via chatgpt but still have problem is in it. Pop have 2 options go to whatsapp channel and don't show notification again. When user click on the don't show notification then it will never show to the user. Can anyone help me please.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="za">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lunchtime Predictions Today</title>
    <style>
        #overlay {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            z-index: 999;
        }

        #popup {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 300px;
            height: 250px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        #closeButton {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        #popupContent {
            flex: 1;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #popupContent p {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #popupContent a,
        #dontShowButton {
            margin-top: 15px;
            color: #1142eb;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #1142eb;
            background-color: transparent;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #popupContent a:hover,
        #dontShowButton:hover {
            background-color: #1142eb;
            color: white;
        }

        #dontShowButton {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="closeButton">X</div>
        <div id="popupContent">
            <p>Join ðŸ¤‘ Confirm 100% <br>UK49s Predictions <br>WhatsApp Group</p><br>
            <a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/LPY2vBhEcQWBH7yJ2s8Gpp">Click here to join</a>
            <button id="dontShowButton">Don't show me again</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function showPopup() {
            console.log('Checking if popup was dismissed...');
            if (!localStorage.getItem('popupDismissed')) {
                console.log('No dismissal found, showing popup...');
                document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                console.log('Popup dismissal found, not showing popup.');
            }
        }

        function closePopup() {
            document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            showPopup();

            document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                closePopup();
            });

            document.getElementById('dontShowButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log('Setting popupDismissed in local storage...');
                localStorage.setItem('popupDismissed', 'true');
                closePopup();
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I want that when user click on the don't show notification then it should not display to the user.
